# How to go to new page and scroll to a particular div using scrollToElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jscrollpane, smooth-scrolling

Hi I am using Jquery scrollToElement to scroll to a particular div on a page (its a single page layout) but now there is a new page. I want to know how to use the same nav to go back to the old page and scroll to particular div do I use index.html#div ?

Answer (score 1):

Write a common function for scrolling to particular div say scroll_me(), Then you can call the function by passing div id on document ready function

Example

```
function scroll_me(id){
  id = id.replace("link", "");
  // Scroll
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},
  'slow');
}
```

You can call this function on

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    scroll_me('particulardiv');
});
```

Comment: Exactly - and in order to control which DIV you go to, you can do this by populating the URL.

$("document").ready(function() {
   if(window.location.href.indexOf("go") > -1) { //go to first div } ...etc

});

Comment: I am using this function but I need to know how to go to another page and then scroll

Comment: You can use window.location.href = "yourpage.html"; then you can call above function in $( document ).ready in yourpage.html

Answer (score 0):

You shoud put slash before #div

```
index.html/#div
```

Comment: The code is at http://netzed.ca/unit.html the nav needs to go back to http://netzed.ca/ and scroll to a particular div

Comment: Than use `http://netzed.ca/#particulardiv` or just `index.html/#particulardiv` but you can't smooth scroll on new page if that's what you're asking.

Comment: This takes me back to the page but not the div still